# Image to Appear Over Image on Hover With CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I know this question has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361924/how-to-display-image-over-image-on-hover-with-css) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549461/overlay-over-image-on-hover)), but for some reason I can't get mine to work when using the same techniques. Basically when you hover over this,

[image]

You should get this:

[image]

By the way, if there's a simpler way to do this without loading a new image when hovering, please let me know.

Here's what I tried:

HTML

```
<div class="image">
<a href="#">
<img class="image" src="wp-content/themes/TheBullshitCollection/Images/bs-1.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
width: 100%;
margin-right: 28px;
margin-bottom: 28px;
display: inline-block;
}

.image a:hover {
display:block;
background-image:url("/wp-content/themes/TheBullshitCollection/Images/bs-1.5.jpg");
margin-right:28px;
margin-bottom:28px;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
width: 100px;
height: 120px;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/ot8a5oba/

You can see that the width and height is also confusing me - I'm not sure how to make sure it stays the same size, and that it appears on top. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that a picture of some shit?

Comment: @EdmundReed Yeah

Comment: literally want code for some shit

Comment: @dxt It's high quality shit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this using a pseudo element to apply an overlay. Simplifies things quite a bit.

```css
.imageContainer a {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.imageContainer a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(139,69,19,0.5);
  content: 'Buy';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font: 5em cursive;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.imageContainer a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imageContainer img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/*
.image a:hover {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/ARiA0ua.jpg");
  margin-right: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/F2PaGob.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it's working but I actually have three images per row and they've lost their margins / correct size now: http://i.imgur.com/VEqUQPw.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/4vLBpSz.jpg Also you can see that the text is too large and there's too much overlay at the bottom....Sorry I should have posted my full code. JS Fiddle link with full code: https://jsfiddle.net/ot8a5oba/1/

Comment: I think I'm able to get the images back to their correct size by adding `height: 105px; width: 95px;` to the `imageContainer img` class, but the problem with the overlay / overlay text being too large is still there....https://jsfiddle.net/ot8a5oba/3/